# Hyperledger Fabric : Balance transfer APIs (User enrollment) Unable to generate key for enrollment due to error

Tags: api, hyperledger-fabric

Hyperledger Fabric : Balance transfer APIs (User enrollment) Unable to generate key for enrollment due to error

I have started runApp.sh and server running in 4000 port as below.

```
[2019-09-23 12:57:59.569] [INFO] SampleWebApp - ****************** SERVER STARTED ************************
[2019-09-23 12:57:59.571] [INFO] SampleWebApp - ***************  http://localhost:4000  ******************
```

While triggering testAPIs.sh like user enrollement, getting error as {
    "success": false,
    "message": "failed Error: Failed to generate key for enrollment due to error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/fabric-client-kv-org1/f1cda0d5560809dd3973f9f791e999a0dedfd00c8d910375b2ac3dd662ecf-priv']"
}

I have provided all group rights to the balance transfer files. 
Started server without sudo permission, node(8.16.0)and npm(6.4.1)

Comment: hmmm .. had you (earlier) run the `runApp.sh` script with sudo?  (seems the current non-sudo user cannot write to that cryptostore directory (`/tmp/fabric-client-kv-org1`) with current permissions)...

Comment: Yes, how i can remove this error?

Comment: remove that tmp sub-directory/contents as your sudo user https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/runApp.sh#L39 - then (as your non-sudo user), run `runApp.sh` again from balance-transfer directory ?

Comment: I deleted the fabric-client-kv-org files and while trying without sudo access, getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you deleted fabric-client-kv-org1 in 
/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/
and /tmp/fabric-client-kv-org1/

Remove both :

in balance-transfer folder

```
rm -rf fabric-client-kv-org1/
```

and

> cd /tmp/

```
rm -rf fabric-client-kv-org1/
rm -rf fabric-client-kv-org2/
```

.
Now start from staring step. Hope it will work.
If any issue, let me know :)